# Instruments Optimization UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, instruments, uicollectionview

I'm loading a bunch of UIImages (that are local and preloaded with the app) with this code:

```
NSString*plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];
for(int i=0;i<array.count; i++) {
    [finalArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]]]];
}
```

then later in the collectionView:

```
cell.cellImage.image = [finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

There's a huge lag on the presentation of that collectionView. I've captured that lag with the following Instruments Screen Shots:

[image]

There's a major disconnect between that lag (experienced by user and shown in the graph) and the actual call Tree below, which shows no delay. I'm loading 500k jpg's in each cell of the collectionView. Is this Instruments analysis basically saying there's nothing I can do in code and this is a system library delay?

EDIT: My question is no longer about this specific use case with my collectionView. It's about Instruments in general. If I have the options selected that I do in the screenshot and the app shows significant lag, but the time profiler doesn't, is there anything I can do to in my code to increase the speed? I'm guess I'm asking more generally about time profiler, settings, and their results. If all the lag is attributed to lower level code or system frameworks, can I do anything about it?

Comment: Can you describe your collectionView a little bit? I'm guessing it's one with a small cell size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `Hide System Libraries` checkbox enabled in the right settings panel so it will hide any calls to methods which you did not define. So for instance, if you make a bunch of calls to `imageNamed:` and you have this checkbox selected, you will not see the time it takes the system to decompress and load these images.

So technically all the "lag"/slowness is in the system frameworks, but it is in your control to change how you use them. And you also can monitor which operations in system frameworks are most expensive time-wise.

Unchecking this box is the solution:

[image: Uncheck this box]

Comment: THis is the kind of feedback I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

[`imageNamed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a) will cache your image.
Use [`imageWithContentsOfFile:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a) to avoid caching.
Hope that will speed up your loading.

Comment: doesn't seem to help:         NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
         [finalArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading them on a background/separate thread, if not then please do it will solve your problem and load them in a queue. So once the image is loaded notify the object that will use it and pass the image object to it.

Create a simple NSOperation that loads an image and notifies the delegate assigned to it. Create object of this class for each image you want to load and add it to NSOperationQueue and set the max concurrent operation count of NSOperationQueue to 1.